# Facebook Messenger bot tokenized payments with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, facebook-messenger

How do I setup tokenized payments with Messenger bots?

I'm getting this error message when submitting a buy button to Facebook messenger:

```
"message":"(#1158) No valid payment provider found. Please add a valid payment provider, it can be tokenized payment, stripe or paypal."
```

But this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/complete-guide/payments#connect_payment_method) says connecting is not necessary for tokenized payments. I have setup an account with Stripe - what do I do now for tokenized payments?

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this the other day the information is on that link your provided, just further down: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/payments-reference#connect_payment_method

Basically, you have to upload a public encryption key to Facebook.  Facebook will use your public key to encrypt the payment information, and then you use your private key to decrypt the information before sending to your preferred payments provider.

If you are trying to use your Stripe account, then you need to link it to your Facebook page that is tied to your bot.  Facebook will then send the payment information to Stripe for you and return the checkout id for the payment.  If you want to use tokenized payments, then you need to decrypt the credit card information and send that to the payment provider of your choice.

Comment: thanks Jalepeno112 - the bot is designed to work with multiple pages, so I don't want to tie the Stripe account to any single page.  Will try setting up the keys and see if that works.